# Play sound from iPad on HomePod

Tags: ipad, audio, ipados, homepod

I have an iPad mini (6th generation) with iPadOS 17 in my hand, running a video in a web browser.

I have a HomePod (2nd generation) in the same room. Using the latest HomePod software from iOS 17.

Can I have the sound from the iPad’s video play on the HomePod?

The goal is better audio quality.

Comment: What have you tried? Is this a problem about you not being aware of the option in Control Center, or did you use that and it didn‘t work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Play audio on HomePod using an iOS or iPadOS device](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/homepod/apdfb81a72e4/homepod) states that it's possible to do (even from the title). Also, [Play audio from iPad on HomePod and other wireless speakers](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/ipad/ipadfb47dca0/ipados) states:

> You can play audio from iPad on wireless devices like HomePod, Apple TV, AirPlay 2-enabled smart TVs, and Bluetooth® headphones and speakers.

However, the articles only describe the solutions when you're using Podcasts, Music or other apps like that which contain an option directly in the app to AirPlay to the HomePod. To stream audio from your iPad (Safari) to your HomePod, you'll have to use AirPlay.

To do this, open the Control Centre on your iPad, click on the [image: AirPlay symbol from https://help.apple.com/assets/6426055D5E9B81542A36F8B9/642605705E9B81542A36F8CA/en_GB/83a75892a6651731e098e384de07a5b1.png] symbol and select your HomePod from the list. Your audio should now play on the HomePod.

Comment: The important point why this is incomplete is that it is not possible to get all sounds to the Homepod

Comment: @mmmmmm It is actually possible to get the sound from a video played on Safari to the HomePod.

Comment: Yes but that is not the only way of playing sounds

Comment: @mmmmmm What do you mean? But I don't see how my answer is incorrect, could you better explain? :)

Comment: I missed the OPs original point saying in very hidden case use web browser. I have the same setup and are constantly annoyed it does not work for some apps and so want to emphasis that. I answered the title. OK OP won't have realised that web browser behaves differently to apps. ALso sounds don"t play but video/music does.

Comment: @mmmmmm Oh. Also, the OP is trying to run a video ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible for apps that use the correct Apple Media APIs and only for Media. So in many cases you cannot.

Game sounds and other non media sounds cannot be played on the Homepod. (If the game is correctly written backgroud music can be played on the Homepod.)

Apps that work will have an icon on screen to choose to Airplay the audio and you then choose the Homepod in the Airplay pop-up.

If the app does not have this function then you might be able to play the sound by going to the iPAd app screen and getting the Control Centre by swiping down at the top right and choosing the Airplay icon to then pop up the choice to use Homepod. See [Apple's documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/homepod/apdfb81a72e4/homepod)

Even then not all apps allow this and you are stuck with iPad speakers - or a bluetooth speaker. Examples of this I have found are Sky and ITV apps.